# Plot normal vector field 3D

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I am implementing the algorithm for [Photometric Stereo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometric_stereo) where I have already calculated the normals from a set of images with different light directions.

How can I plot the normal vector field in matlab? I have a matrix of normals of size (N x 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you have left out a step. You need to retrieve the depth map from the surface normals, and then you can start plotting. To see how to do this, you can check out section 4 of the following paper:

http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/photostereo/Photometric%20Stereo%20with%20General%20Unknown%20Lighting%20-%20BasriJacobsKemelmacher_ijcv06.pdf

There are other resources on the web too; I don't know of any built-in function in any Matlab library, but I don't have the Computer Vision toolbox, so who knows?

Comment: Thanks, I actually computed the DepthMap and then used surf(DepthMap, Albedo) in order to see the surface

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking for [quiver3](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html).

Comment: But for quiver3 it asks for a point (x,y,z) and the normal (u,v,w) but I only have the values of the normal. Any suggestion?

Comment: Then what do you intend to plot? if you only have a set of vectors all you can is plot them as some kind of point cloud, but that is not what you want. Every normal is attached to something, a surface, a polygon, a pixel, whatever, this origin for each normal you need to determine, which is your xyz.

Comment: Actually the problem I'm trying to solve is the surface reconstruction via Photometric Stereo. So, given a set of images with different lighting directions, under certain assumptions we can recover the normal map and then reconstruct the surface from this normal map. I wanted to plot the normal map to see how the surface more or less looks like before trying to reconstruct the surface.

Comment: Then your question isn't about plotting, It's about implicit surface construction. You cannot plot anything until you have constructed the surface, which is your xyz input to quiver3.

Comment: Yep the problem is about plotting, but that problem implied reconstructing the surface which I did and the plot was fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to present  normals field, as an gradient field, then you can,use quiver function. And in gradient field previously normalized triple {pn,qn,rn}, the data is presented in such a way , as to rend the third component of it always equal to one (at least in theory). I mean with rn=1, or should I now say, that now : R=1, and you actually need only {P,Q} coomponents to present contents of gradient field with ordinary 2D quiver function. Thus, gradient vector is something quite different and distinct from normals field, because: P=pn/sqrt(pn^2+qn^2+rn^2) , and Q=qn/(pn^2+qn^2+rn^2) POINTWISELY saying. 
However you don't bother with double for loops, run over X,Y directions, cause POINTWISELY, correctly rendered calculations for gradient field from normals, is the following: P=pn./(pn.^2 + qn.^2 + rn.^2).^(1/2);, and so on. 
You can see as well: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/126090/

Answer (score 0):

You need to present  normals field, as an gradient field, then you can use a Matlab's quiver function. And in gradient field, the previously normalized triple {pn,qn,rn}, of the data, is presented in such a way, as to rend the third component of it always equal to one (at least in theory).

I mean with rn = 1, or should I now say, that now with: some R=1, you actually need only {P,Q} coomponents to present contents of gradient field with ordinary 2D quiver function. Thus, gradient vector is something quite different and distinct from normals field, because: 
P=pn/sqrt(pn^2+qn^2+rn^2) , and Q=qn/(pn^2+qn^2+rn^2) POINTWISELY saying.

However you don't bother with double for loops, which would be run over X, Y directions, cause POINTWISELY, correctly rendered calculations for gradient field from normals, are the following:

P=pn./(pn.^2 + qn.^2 + rn.^2).^(1/2);  , and:  Q=qn./(pn.^2 + qn.^2 + rn.^2);

You can see as well: 
  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/126090/

Briefly saying, the gradient field always represents slopes on X, Y directions, while descending exactly one height unit alongside Z axis on the 3D surface retrieved with  for instance Photometric Stereo algorithm. That is why the third component in quiver function visualization is always equal to one (i.e. R = 1), and practically irrelevant.

I have posted, last month, some codes, on THE simplest Photometric Stereo methods, on Mathworks Web pages, due to some span of time available to tide it all up, I mean my own so far produced codes in Matlab...